# Unable to Log events in Application Event viewer - WinRun4J

Tags: java, winrun4j

Using the command as described

> EventLog.report("WinRun4J Test Service", EventLog.INFORMATION,
>   "Ping");

Instead of writing the event logs it writes this

> The description for Event ID 0 from source WinRun4J Test Service
>   cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not
>   installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You
>   can install or repair the component on the local computer.

The information is written in byte data "Ping"

Whereas running the WinRun4JTest app as service it successfully writes the event logs in "SystemEventLogs"

What am i missing here ?

Comment: I have the same problem on windows 7. Did you solved the problem?

Comment: I went on using log4j